# Infinite loop kohana api response

Tags: php, kohana, httprequest, kohana-3

So this is kinda funny

when i try to access a API that i made with Kohana over the browser -> 200 [OK]

when i try anything else like file_get_contents or curl -> infinite loop -> timeout

I'm using Kohana 3.3 PHP 5.4.4 and CURL 7.24.0

any ideas, because this is not funny anymore?

edit:

so this loop keeps looping

```
do {
    $execValue = curl_multi_exec($this->mutliCurl, $running);
} while ($running > 0);
```

this is how a request is added

```
public function add(Kohana_Rest_Request $request){
    curl_multi_add_handle($this->mutliCurl, $request->getCurl());
    $this->requestQueue[] = $request;

    return $this;
}
```

when i debug(i did all ready the bit by bit part) i add 4 curls with the add function, but the loop keeps looping...?! that is the weird part

Comment: Well, as infinite loops are mainly caused by bad code, maybe post some of your code.

Comment: well i think so too, but the problem is ive created a kohana modude, another module on top of that...soooo...its kinda a problem to post it:D...

Comment: In that case we cannot help you. Try debugging bits of code and narrow it down. Good luck!

Comment: If you take a look at [curl_multi_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) (the example) you can see thay use `$execValue` in the `do {} while()` loop instead of `$running`. Try that see if it helps.